# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characterb (Python error)

Tags: python

I want to write a simple python program to find most frequent words in a file.
The content of my file looks like this:

```
<text>աաա բբբ գգգ աաաա բբբ</text>
.....
<text>բբբ աաագգգ աաաա բբբ</text>
.....
<text>աաաաաաա բբբ հհհհ բբբ գգգ </text>
```

This is my Python code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import collections
a = open('dump.txt', encoding='UTF-8', errors='replace')
contents = a.read()
articlelist = re.findall(r'<text[^>]+>([^<]+)</text>', contents, re.M)
wordsandnumber = []
for article in articlelist:
    wordsinarticle = re.findall(r'\w+', article)
    for finaly in wordsinarticle:
        wordsandnumber.append(finaly)
counter = collections.Counter(wordsandnumber)
mylist = counter.most_common()
open('as.txt', 'w').write('\n'.join('%s %s' % x for x in mylist))
print(counter.most_common())
```

But the code doesn't work correctly because of this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\Downloads\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    open('as.txt', 'w').write('\n'.join('%s %s' % x for x in mylist))
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0567' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am a beginner in programming ։/ Please help me to solve this problem and understand why this code doesn't work.

And if it matters at all: I am using Windows 10, and Python 3.5.

Comment: You should read the [Unicode How To](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) on Python's website

Comment: In what encoding do you want your output file to be? If UTF-8 is fine, then open the output file as follows: `open('as.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')`.

Comment: Jakub, thanks for the link.
@Leon, thank you very much! Now it works.